# Python - PyMongo Insert and Update

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to do an Insert and Update operation on my seat, without the insertion of duplicate data.

My collection has the id attribute that to which I made an operating `createIndex()` to pass the id attribute as unique. It works because every time I try to enter new data through my code in Python, appears the message:

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test index: id_1 dup key: { : "400728540046889_1108783115908091" }
```

Ok, mongoDB is not letting enter data that is already stored in the bank. But I need my code to continue running ignoring the new data already ExSite in the bank and continue to enter new ones. The working order this:

Run the script - Insert command in the Bank - Error: Dup Key

and what I look for is:

Run the script - Insert command in the Bank - Error: Dup Key (Ignore this key) - Continues running the script looking for new data and inserting

I, tried to use the Update approach with upsert, using the command:

```
db.myDB.update({'id':status['id']},status,True)
```

Here we have:

- Status: Contains my data
- Id: Field in status, contains the ID of the text.

The problem is: He's entering duplicate data with the same id, only now putting all under _id: ObjectId of mongoDB.

How can i use an approach that I can enter new data and not re-enter data that already exist in the bank?

Comment: go through the link for basics https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html. you keep the code which is error prone (insert operation) in the try block and you catch the error/exception (here, DuplicateKeyError) in except block. in the except block, use continue (python keyword) to run the code in case of DuplicateKeyError.

Comment: Like `try: 
    insert....
    except DuplicateKeyError as err:
    continue` ?

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

```
try:
    # insertion logic
except DuplicateKeyError as err:
    continue;  # will continue though DuplicateKeyError is raised.
```

Comment: Edit: Ok, the error is `pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError` But even in this case, the new data is not entered in the collection of mongo.

Comment: The new data is being entered, but are not in order (newest -> older). They are inserted into the middle of the collection

Comment: why would that matters to you (the order in which docs are stored), where you retrieve the records in the order you want using the sort functionality.